# How to use ansible through bastion to private subnet in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

I have been trying to figure this out for the past 2 days and am getting no where

What I am trying to do is from my home server (Centos7) run ansible playbooks to configure AWS linux (centos7) servers on a private subnet in AWS.

If I run:

```
sshpass -p "PASSWORD" ssh -i "/aws_ssh/KEY_PAIR.pem" -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" -t ansibleuser@PUBLICBASTIONHOSTIP 'sshpass -p "PASSWORD" ssh -i "/aws_ssh/KEY_PAIR.pem" -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" ansibleuser@PRIVATEHOSTIP'
```

I can connect to from my home to my AWS server on the private subnet

```
/etc/ansible/hosts
[webservers:vars]
ansible_user=ec2-user
ansible_become=yes
ansible_become_method=sudo
ansible_become_pass='PASSWORD'
ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o ProxyCommand="ssh ssh -i /aws_ssh/_KEY_PAIR.pem -t -W %h:%p -q ec2-user@IPADDRESS"'
[webservers]
10.150.2.15
10.150.4.15

test.yml
---
- name: This sets up an httpd webserver
  hosts: webservers
  tasks:
  - name: example
    command: hostname
```

What I am trying to achieve is when I run:

```
   [ec2-user@terraform playbook]$ ansible-playbook test.yml -vvvv
ansible-playbook 2.9.6
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/ec2-user/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, Aug  7 2019, 00:51:29) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)]
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
setting up inventory plugins
host_list declined parsing /etc/ansible/hosts as it did not pass its verify_file() method
script declined parsing /etc/ansible/hosts as it did not pass its verify_file() method
auto declined parsing /etc/ansible/hosts as it did not pass its verify_file() method
Parsed /etc/ansible/hosts inventory source with ini plugin
Loading callback plugin default of type stdout, v2.0 from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/default.pyc

PLAYBOOK: test.yml **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Positional arguments: test.yml
become_method: sudo
inventory: (u'/etc/ansible/hosts',)
forks: 5
tags: (u'all',)
verbosity: 4
connection: smart
timeout: 10
1 plays in test.yml

PLAY [This sets up an httpd webserver] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /playbook/test.yml:2
<10.150.2.15> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ec2-user
<10.150.2.15> SSH: EXEC ssh -vvv -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="ec2-user"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/ec2-user/.ansible/cp/f72ac484f5 10.150.2.15 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~ec2-user && sleep 0'"'"''
<10.150.4.15> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ec2-user
<10.150.4.15> SSH: EXEC ssh -vvv -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="ec2-user"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/ec2-user/.ansible/cp/a6bd87bb6f 10.150.4.15 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~ec2-user && sleep 0'"'"''
<10.150.2.15> (255, '', 'OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *\r\ndebug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master\r\ndebug1: Control socket "/home/ec2-user/.ansible/cp/f72ac484f5" does not exist\r\ndebug2: resolving "10.150.2.15" port 22\r\ndebug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0\r\ndebug1: Connecting to 10.150.2.15 [10.150.2.15] port 22.\r\ndebug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug1: connect to address 10.150.2.15 port 22: Connection timed out\r\nssh: connect to host 10.150.2.15 port 22: Connection timed out\r\n')
fatal: [10.150.2.15]: UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *\r\ndebug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master\r\ndebug1: Control socket \"/home/ec2-user/.ansible/cp/f72ac484f5\" does not exist\r\ndebug2: resolving \"10.150.2.15\" port 22\r\ndebug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0\r\ndebug1: Connecting to 10.150.2.15 [10.150.2.15] port 22.\r\ndebug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug1: connect to address 10.150.2.15 port 22: Connection timed out\r\nssh: connect to host 10.150.2.15 port 22: Connection timed out",
    "unreachable": true
}
<10.150.4.15> (255, '', 'OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *\r\ndebug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master\r\ndebug1: Control socket "/home/ec2-user/.ansible/cp/a6bd87bb6f" does not exist\r\ndebug2: resolving "10.150.4.15" port 22\r\ndebug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0\r\ndebug1: Connecting to 10.150.4.15 [10.150.4.15] port 22.\r\ndebug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug1: connect to address 10.150.4.15 port 22: Connection timed out\r\nssh: connect to host 10.150.4.15 port 22: Connection timed out\r\n')
fatal: [10.150.4.15]: UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *\r\ndebug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master\r\ndebug1: Control socket \"/home/ec2-user/.ansible/cp/a6bd87bb6f\" does not exist\r\ndebug2: resolving \"10.150.4.15\" port 22\r\ndebug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0\r\ndebug1: Connecting to 10.150.4.15 [10.150.4.15] port 22.\r\ndebug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug1: connect to address 10.150.4.15 port 22: Connection timed out\r\nssh: connect to host 10.150.4.15 port 22: Connection timed out",
    "unreachable": true
}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
10.150.2.15               : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
10.150.4.15               : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

What am I doing wrong?

What I do not want to do is log into the bastion host and then run ansible commands.

Comment: what errors are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with some clever use of Ansible arguments. First create an inventory file with host groups that you can run individual tasks/plays against. At least one of these groups should be your Bastion and one in your private subnet.

Record the IP Address of your Bastion and create a new Jinja2 variable in your Play that targets the server in the private subnet. After that, create a new Play in your Playbook that passes a `vars` option to your private subnet host group referencing this variable and more.

```
- hosts: private_subnet
  vars:
    - ansible_ssh_user: "example"
    - ansible_ssh_common_args: >
          -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -q {{ ansible_ssh_user }}@{{ bastion_ip }}" \
          -o ServerAliveInterval=5 \
          -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
  tasks:
    - name: example
      debug:
        msg: Hello World from {{ inventory_hostname }}!
```

You should be able to follow this with any tasks you want and Ansible will tunnel all traffic through the Bastion.

I've successfully done this a handful of times. One good enhancement is automatically discovering the IP Address of your Bastion server with a role that performs and API call to AWS EC2 instead of manually creating and manipulating the `bastion_ip` variable.

Comment: Thank you for the attempt, however did not work, I have updated my question

Comment: As mentioned I have successfully applied this method in production a handful of times. If you provide some Infrastructure as Code to provision an environment to replicate yours, I'd be happy to continue testing. But as of now, if I look at the solution I have live in production and look at the solution I propose for you they are the same. My workstation uses Ansible to deploy software and configure systems on servers that are on a private subnet behind a Bastion. In fact, they are entirely air gapped from outer networks as well. The Bastion is their only means of communication to the outside.

Comment: Can you provide your inventory file?

Comment: If you look at the first SSH argument you can see that I am passing `bastion_ip`. This is a reference to a variable that is dynamically set by a task that runs in another play. The Bastion, in this case, is not present in the inventory file. Playbooks initially target `localhost` which performs API calls to AWS to determine the IP Addresses of target machines. The IPs are registered as variables and then accessed using `hostvars` by tasks in other plays. For example: `{{ hostvars['localhost'].bastion_ip.stdout }}`